# Adding a variable value as an option in a PHP echo created drop down menu

Tags: php, html, select, menu

I am using a PHP script within an HTML page to create a dropdown menu with results populated from a database. I am using the PHP script in the HTML page because I'd like the dropdown menu to remain on the same page as a number of options.

When creating an option in the dropdown menu via an echo, it won't allow me to use the value of a variable (i.e. the value of a field in the database that has been retrieved) in the option tag. Here is the code:

```
<select name="comics">
    <OPTION>Select an option</OPTION>; 
    <?php
        include_once('includes/conn.inc.php');
        $query = ("SELECT comicID, comicName  FROM comic");
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
        echo "<option> .$row['comicName']. </option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

As is, the code creates the drop down menu and adds the "Select an option" line. The second option is created, but the value reads as " .$row['comicName']. "  instead of, for example, "Superman".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `echo "<option value='".$row['comicName']."'>".$row['comicName']." </option>";`

Comment: The output is still:

".$row['comicName']."

Comment: you can do it without echo this way: ?> <option> <?php print $row['comicName'];?> </option> <?php (Use php only when really needed)

Comment: The above method returns a blank value, unfortunately.

Comment: If is blank than you've got problem on include.once or $query or $conn =)

Comment: Have you named the file with a php extension ? try doing a print_r with $result before the while loop.

Comment: The .php extension solved it. Thanks so much!

Comment: I would mark your answer as correct but I can't seem to do it in the comments.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer, Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you named the file with a php extension ? try doing a print_r with $result before the while loop

Comment: Changing to .php solved the issue. Can't believe it never occurred to me. Then again I've only had to make .html for this sort of thing up until now. Learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution tries performing concatenation without closing the double-quotes first, so it treats the variable as a string. Try this:

```
echo "<option>" . $row['comicName'] . "</option>";
```

Comment: Output is still " . $row['comicName'] . "

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<select name="comics">
    <OPTION>Select an option</OPTION>; 
    <?php
        include_once('includes/conn.inc.php');
        $query = ("SELECT comicID, comicName  FROM comic");
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
        echo "<option value='".$row['comicName']."'>".$row['comicName']."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Let me know if works.